# Wrong External IP for Real Server Behind Load Balancer

Tags: networking, centos, load-balancing

I have a hardware load balancer with multiple Virtual IPs. ie (3.3.3.3, 3.3.3.4).

Behind Virtual IP 3.3.3.3 I am load balancing several web servers.

Behind VIP 3.3.3.4 I have a mail server running CentOS.

Unfortunately, when I send out mail, it appears to be coming from VIP 3.3.3.3 rather than 3.3.3.4. Similarly, if I use the dig +short txt ch whoami.cloudflare @1.0.0.1 command, it returns 3.3.3.3.

How can I specify that the server behind VIP 3.3.3.4 actually shows to the world as 3.3.3.4?

Thank you!

Comment: my first thought is that it is some configuration in *a hardware load balancer* - unfortunately it's difficult to get the specs for *a hardware load balancer*

Comment: It seems your mail server is listening at VIP 3.3.3.4 but sending via the default gateway at VIP 3.3.3.3. At least that's what I understand from your post. Maybe you could enhance your question.

Comment: the mail server gateway is the lan ip of the barracuda load balancer. unfortunately, i can't see any route configuration options in the gui to correct this.